# Program which compare conditional line repetitions and print specific sum in AWK

Tags: awk

I have a big problem. I need to write a program that compares lines between two files (File1, File2 and we print a sum of repetitions to another file Sum1, but there are several conditions. We check what we have in column2 ($2), the most important are SOL repetitions, SOL can repeat 2 times, 3 times or 4 times:

1. For 2 same SOL repetitions we add one

a) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD107 SOL5989
DGD107 SOL5989
```

we add 1 to sum

b) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD167 SOL5989
DGD1071 SOL5989
```

we add 1 to sum

2. For 3 same SOL repetitions we add 2 (we have 3 different types of 3-times repetitions)"

a) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD67 SOL3641
DGD1911 SOL3641
DGD123 SOL3641
```

we add to sum 2

b) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD87 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234
```

we add to sum 2
c) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD429 SOL619
DGD429 SOL619
DGD429 SOL619
```

we add to sum 2

3. For 4 same SOL repetitions we also add **2** (we have 5 different types of 4-times repetitions)

a) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD5 SOL2848
DGD5 SOL2848
DGD5 SOL2848
DGD59 SOL2848
```

we add to sum 2

b) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD99 SOL4509
DGD99 SOL4509
DGD99 SOL4509
DGD99 SOL4509
```

we add to sum 2

c) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD7 SOL601
DGD34 SOL601
DGD34 SOL601
DGD63 SOL601
```

we add to sum 2

d) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD74 SOL130
DGD78 SOL130
DGD18 SOL130
DGD72 SOL130
```

we add to sum 2

e) In File1 and in File2

```
DGD7 SOL172
DGD34 SOL172
DGD34 SOL172
DGD7 SOL172
```

we add to sum 2

Ok, so This is the code example (I add spaces to help you see it)

File1

```
DGD5 SOL2848
DGD5 SOL2848
DGD5 SOL2848
DGD59 SOL2848

DGD87 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234

DGD5 SOL5989
DGD5 SOL5989

DGD87 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234

DGD74 SOL130
DGD78 SOL130
DGD18 SOL130
DGD72 SOL130
```

File2

```
DGD72 SOL782
DGD5 SOL2848
DGD5 SOL2848
DGD72 SOL782

DGD87 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234

DGD107 SOL5989
DGD107 SOL5989

DGD52 SOL571
DGD22 SOL571
DGD5019 SOL1234
DGD5019 SOL1234

DGD74 SOL130
DGD78 SOL130
DGD18 SOL130
DGD72 SOL130
```

The sum should be 6 (I gave you 5 examples of repetitions: 1st 1; 2nd 2; 3rd 0; 4th 1; 5th 2).

I know that this is a super hard task, but any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You'll stand a better chance of getting an answer if you post 1 question with 1 sample input/output data set. Then you can try to apply that solution to your other problems and ask a followup question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @EdMorton you're right. I will try to divide my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output `6` for given sample input:

```
awk '
  NF < 2 {next}
  NR==FNR {
    c1[$2] += c1[$2]<3
    next
  }
  c1[$2]-->0 && c2[$2]++ {++sum}
  END {print sum+0}
' file[12]
```

It seems that condition 3. (adding 2 to sum for 4 repeats) is already covered when 2. (3 repeats) has been counted. The process is: increment sum if $2 appears twice in both files; and increment sum once more if $2 appears more than twice in both files.